# How to use startTLS with ldaptor?

Tags: python, ldap, twisted, starttls

I'm trying to use ldaptor to connect via startTLS to a LDAP server. Searching on internet and trying myself I arrived to this snippet of code:

```
from ldaptor.protocols.ldap import ldapclient, ldapsyntax, ldapconnector, distinguishedname
[...]
def main(base, serviceLocationOverrides):
    c=ldapconnector.LDAPClientCreator(reactor, ldapclient.LDAPClient)
    d = c.connect(base, serviceLocationOverrides)
    d.addCallbacks(lambda proto: proto.startTLS(), error)
    [...]
    d.addErrback(error)
    d.addBoth(lambda dummy: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```

but the code exits with an AssertionError:

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>: 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py:1167:mainLoop
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py:789:runUntilCurrent
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:361:callback
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:455:_startRunCallbacks
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py:542:_runCallbacks
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/ldaptor/protocols/ldap/ldapclient.py:239:_startTLS
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/ldaptor/protocols/pureldap.py:1278:__init__
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/ldaptor/protocols/pureldap.py:1144:__init__
]
```

I have tried to look in ldaptor code for the incriminated assertion but seems all ok.
Is there someone who succeded in using ldaptorClient startTLS? 
A code snippet?

Thank you very much

Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that your problem is one I ran into a while back.  In ldaptor/protocols/pureldap.py, line 1144 asserts that the LDAPExtendedRequest requestValue must be a string.  But according to RFC 2251, that value is optional, and specifically should NOT be present in startTLS requests.

So your approach is correct; this is just a major bug in ldaptor.  As far as I can tell, the author only tested using simple bind without TLS.  You need to comment out that line in pureldap.py.  If you're deploying this with the expectation that users will download or easy-install ldaptor, then you'll need to create a fixed copy of the LDAPExtendedRequest class in your own code, and sub it in at run-time.

Having had to maintain a project using ldaptor for several years, I would strongly urge you to switch to python-ldap if at all possible.  Since it wraps the OpenLDAP libs, it can be much more difficult to build, especially with full support for SSL/SASL.  But it's well worth it, because ldaptor has a lot more problems than just the one you ran across.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm already using python-ldap ina a twisted based project and hoped to get higher integration with ldaptor. I don't like to deferToThread every single call to ldap, and working with the asyncronous version of the python-ldap calls inside the reactor loop is a mess (the only way I found was to poll the ldap server results with ldap.callLater every now and then)

Anyway, thank you again for your useful answer

Comment: While this may have been true in 2011, in 2014 I had no problem getting ldaptor to use StartTLS.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Using ldaptor 0.0.54 from https://github.com/twisted/ldaptor, I had no problems using StartTLS.

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python


from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from ldaptor.protocols.ldap import ldapclient, ldapsyntax, ldapconnector

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def example():
    serverip = 'your.server.name.or.ip'
    basedn = 'o=Organization'
    binddn = 'cn=admin,o=Organization'
    bindpw = 'Sekret'
    query = '(uid=jetsong)'
    c = ldapconnector.LDAPClientCreator(reactor, ldapclient.LDAPClient)
    overrides = {basedn: (serverip, 389)}
    client = yield c.connect(basedn, overrides=overrides)
    client = yield client.startTLS()
    yield client.bind(binddn, bindpw)
    o = ldapsyntax.LDAPEntry(client, basedn)
    results = yield o.search(filterText=query)
    for entry in results:
        print entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = example()
    df.addErrback(lambda err: err.printTraceback())
    df.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```